# How to find examples of evolved/extended papers for a particular journal?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, extended-paper

My evolved/extended paper for IEEE T-RO was rejected due to a lack of additional research impact from the original conference proceeding. In order to improve my submission, I'd like to find examples of papers that have been extended from conference proceedings in this particular journal and compare the extended paper with the conference proceeding. Is there a combination of search terms I can use, either on IEEE Xplore or elsewhere, to find evolved/extended papers along with the original conference proceedings?

Comment: We can't suggest search terms and strategies in your particular area, where you know more than we do.

Comment: @EthanBolker I would surmise there may be terms that are common to repositories across multiple disciplines and fields, so I think it's worth asking.